# Cant style Bootstrap and normal elements

Tags: html, css, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I can not seem to style my website... for example the `<pre>` tags.

Nothing I do works. I am trying to style the whois results, I've tried wrapping it in a div and styling that, styling the pre tags only, styling everything. I just can't seem to get it working. I am hoping I am missing something stupid.  You can see from the CSS I have tried numerous combinations (tried deleting them all just having pre ect)

Nav bar:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="generator" content="PSPad editor, www.pspad.com">
  <title>CWCS Domain Checker Tool</title>
</head>
<body>
<!--- This Keeps the navbar from staying right near top -->
<div class="header">
</div>

<!---- Nav bar, Using bootstrap ----->
<nav class="navbar navbar">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
       <div class="nav-bar-logo">
      <a href="index.php" class="navbar-left"><img src="images/cwcs-logo.png"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="nav-list-container">
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="domaindiagnostics.php">Domain Diagnostics</a></li>
      <li><a id="sd" href="#">Server Diagnostics</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Second Line Tools
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a id="dc" href="#">Daily Checklist</a></li>
          <li><a id="bt" href="#">Backup Tracker</a></li>
          <li><a id="tl" href="#">Task List</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<!------- End of nav bar ---->
```

Main page -

```
<?php
## Includes nav bar
include('navbar.php');
include('phpfiles/domainclass.php');

if (isset($_GET['userInput'])) 
{
    $domainName = $_GET['userInput'];
}

?>

<!---- The input form ---->
<form class="form">
<div class="domainquery">
  <div class="input-group">
      <input id="domainName" name="userInput" class="form-control input-md" type="text" placeholder="example.com" value="<?php if (isset($domainName)) echo $domainName ?>" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Query Domain</button>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
<!---- End of input form --->

<!---- start of content --->
<div class ="container-fluid">

<!----- Check of the variable has been set before showing --->
  <?php 
    ##checks if the variable name $domainName is set, before loading everything below
    if (isset($domainName)): 
  ?>
  <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

  <h3>DNS Records </h3>
          <div class="dnscontain">
                  <script>
                      // Loads the return vaue of the call into the "dnscontain" div.
                      $(".dnscontain").load("ajaxhandler.php", 
                      {  // ajax call to pass variable to ajax handler, which then decides what to do with it        
                               d: "<?php echo $domainName ?>",
                               q: 'dns'
                      });
                    </script> 

          </div>

  <h3>SSL Result</h3>


  <h3>NMAP Result</h3>
          <div class="nmapcontain">
                    <script>
                      // Loads the return vaue of the call into the "dnscontain" div.
                      $(".nmapcontain").load("ajaxhandler.php", 
                      {  // ajax call to pass variable to ajax handler, which then decides what to do with it        
                               d: "<?php echo $domainName ?>",
                               q: 'nmap'
                      });
                    </script> 
          </div>
  <h3>PING Result</h3>
                  <div class="pingcontain">
                    <script>
                      // Loads the return vaue of the call into the "dnscontain" div.
                      $(".pingcontain").load("ajaxhandler.php", 
                      {  // ajax call to pass variable to ajax handler, which then decides what to do with it        
                               d: "<?php echo $domainName ?>",
                               q: 'ping'
                      });
                    </script> 
                  </div>
<!--- Closing div tag for left column -->        
</div>

<!--- starting right column -->
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <h3>WHOIS Result</h3>
          <div class="whoiscontain">
                    <script>
                            // Loads the return vaue of the call into the "whoiscontain" div.
                           $(".whoiscontain").load("ajaxhandler.php", 
                            {  // ajax call to pass variable to ajax handler, which then decides what to do with it      
                               d: "<?php echo $domainName ?>",
                               q: 'whois'
                            });
                    </script> 
          <!--Whoiscontain div end -->          
          </div>
 <!--- right column div end -->         
  </div>

<!--- closing div tag for 1st row --->
</div>
 </div> 
<!---- ends the check on if the variable is set -->          
<?php
###End the "IF" check 
endif 
?>

<!---- Closing div tag for container-fluid --->
</div> 


</body>
</html>
```

Ajax return page --

```
<?php
include 'domainclass.php';

$result = domain::getWhois($domainName);
?>

<pre class="whois">  <?php echo $result ?> </pre>;
```

Style sheet

```
.header
{
  margin:1%;
}


.domainquery
{
    margin-bottom:3%;
    padding:40px 50px;
}

.nav-bar-logo
{
  margin-right:20px;
  padding-right:20px;
}

.table
{
  font-size:5px;
}
pre .whois
{
white-space:pre-wrap;
background-color:black;
color:white;
word-wrap: break-word;
}

.whoiscontain
{
white-space:pre-wrap;
background-color:black;
width:100%;
color:white;
word-wrap: break-word;
}

pre
{
white-space:pre-wrap;
background-color:black;
color:white;
word-wrap: break-word;

}
```

HTML output of page as requested (ignore style sheeting being above the bootstrap stylesheet, was trying something.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="generator" content="PSPad editor, www.pspad.com">
  <title>CWCS Domain Checker Tool</title>
</head>
<body>
<!--- This Keeps the navbar from staying right near top -->
<div class="header">
</div>

<!---- Nav bar, Using bootstrap ----->
<nav class="navbar navbar">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
       <div class="nav-bar-logo">
      <a href="index.php" class="navbar-left"><img src="images/cwcs-logo.png"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="nav-list-container">
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="domaindiagnostics.php">Domain Diagnostics</a></li>
      <li><a id="sd" href="#">Server Diagnostics</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Second Line Tools
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a id="dc" href="#">Daily Checklist</a></li>
          <li><a id="bt" href="#">Backup Tracker</a></li>
          <li><a id="tl" href="#">Task List</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<!------- End of nav bar ---->

<!---- The input form ---->
<form class="form">
<div class="domainquery">
  <div class="input-group">
      <input id="domainName" name="userInput" class="form-control input-md" type="text" placeholder="example.com" value="lomcn.org" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Query Domain</button>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
<!---- End of input form --->

<!---- start of content --->
<div class ="container-fluid">

<!----- Check of the variable has been set before showing --->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

  <h3>DNS Records </h3>
          <div class="dnscontain">
                  <script>
                      // Loads the return vaue of the call into the "dnscontain" div.
                      $(".dnscontain").load("ajaxhandler.php", 
                      {  // ajax call to pass variable to ajax handler, which then decides what to do with it        
                               d: "lomcn.org",
                               q: 'dns'
                      });
                    </script> 

          </div>

  <h3>SSL Result</h3>


  <h3>NMAP Result</h3>
          <div class="nmapcontain">
                    <script>
                      // Loads the return vaue of the call into the "dnscontain" div.
                      $(".nmapcontain").load("ajaxhandler.php", 
                      {  // ajax call to pass variable to ajax handler, which then decides what to do with it        
                               d: "lomcn.org",
                               q: 'nmap'
                      });
                    </script> 
          </div>
  <h3>PING Result</h3>
                  <div class="pingcontain">
                    <script>
                      // Loads the return vaue of the call into the "dnscontain" div.
                      $(".pingcontain").load("ajaxhandler.php", 
                      {  // ajax call to pass variable to ajax handler, which then decides what to do with it        
                               d: "lomcn.org",
                               q: 'ping'
                      });
                    </script> 
                  </div>

    <h3>Tracert Result</h3>
                  <div class="tracecontain">
                    <script>
                      // Loads the return vaue of the call into the "dnscontain" div.
                      $(".tracecontain").load("ajaxhandler.php", 
                      {  // ajax call to pass variable to ajax handler, which then decides what to do with it        
                               d: "lomcn.org",
                               q: 'trace'
                      });
                    </script> 
                  </div>
<!--- Closing div tag for left column -->        
</div>

<!--- starting right column -->
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <h3>WHOIS Result</h3>
          <div class="whoiscontain">
                    <script>
                            // Loads the return vaue of the call into the "whoiscontain" div.
                           $(".whoiscontain").load("ajaxhandler.php", 
                            {  // ajax call to pass variable to ajax handler, which then decides what to do with it      
                               d: "lomcn.org",
                               q: 'whois'
                            });
                    </script> 
          <!--Whoiscontain div end -->          
          </div>
 <!--- right column div end -->         
  </div>

<!--- closing div tag for 1st row --->
</div>
 </div> 
<!---- ends the check on if the variable is set -->          

<!---- Closing div tag for container-fluid --->
</div> 


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: change `pre .whois` to `pre.whois` and fix your `link` tag per @tilz0R's answer

Comment: missing " < " tag was a copy and paste error.   Tried pre.whois  still no joy ><  I want to style ALL "pre's" the same tbf, but even the just pre css selector does not seem to be having any effect. strange thing is some of the css is working e.g the  header/navbar logo work fine

Comment: Instead of showing us the php and ajax response, can you just put the HTML that is rendered in the browser for the page here so that we don't have to put those pieces together for you just to see a CSS issue?

Comment: added to bottom post, i included the ajax ect as I think thats the reason its not working,.

Comment: Is any CSS you write working? Are you 100% sure the file you are writing CSS to is successfully being picked up by the browser?

Answer (score 0):

to style bootstrap you can over ride bootstrap styles or make your own new styles.

They recommend not editing the bootstrap .CSS directly so updates to bootstrap will not change your design.

You are correct to place your own style sheet call below the bootstrap call, so yours will override.

Even though your styles will over ride you might not be able to over ride a bootstrap rule that has the !important tag. You can either use the bootstrap classes and ID's in your stylesheet and make new rules, using your own !Important to force them through if necessary, or add additional classes for your styles:

[a bit of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6Ajo.png)

```
    was `<div class="col-md-12">`

    make `<div class="col-md-12 myCol">`
```

and then make rules on  your stylesheet for

.myCol{
these styles should persist
}